# Get dictionary of dtypes as read in by Pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, types

I have a large Pandas dataframe that I've imported from a SQL database. The whole process takes several hours. As I work on the data, inevitably the dataframe gets altered and I regularly want to go back to 'a known good dataset' and re-run various functions. Instead of importing the data from the database, I want to save the data at various points of the analysis process as CSV files which can then be used to restore the data as required; CSV is the format of choice because, for some reason, I haven't had much luck with pickling the dataframes. Simply importing the CSV data using pd.read_csv() alters the datatypes of the columns. As a result, I want to create a dictionary of dtypes which can be used to restore the data types when importing the CSV back into a dataframe.

As an example, a simple dataframe may be defined as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':['a','b','c','d','e'],'C':[1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.0]},index=[0,2,4,6,8])
```

which looks like:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  a  1.2
2  2  b  3.4
4  3  c  5.6
6  4  d  7.8
8  5  e  9.0
```

A dictionary of dtypes can be created using:

```
dtypesDict = df.dtypes.to_dict()
```

which produces:

```
{'B': dtype('O'), 'C': dtype('float64'), 'A': dtype('int64')}
```

If I try to use this output to define a dictionary in hard-code so it can be used to set the data types for the columns which are imported using `pd.read_csv()`, it fails as follows:

```
dtypesDict = {'B': dtype('O'), 'C': dtype('float64'), 'A': dtype('int64')}

NameError: name 'dtype' is not defined
```

However, defining the dictionary as:

```
dtypesDict = {'B': 'O', 'C': 'float64', 'A': 'int64'}
```

allows the CSV file to be imported with no problems.

I thought a dictionary comprehension was the way to go but I can't make that work:

```
dtypesDict = {k:bit_in_brackets_of_v for k,v in df.dtypes.to_dict().items()}
```

How can I automatically produce a dictionary of the correct format that can be defined in hard-code using cut a simple cut-and-paste process and will allow dtypes of columns imported from a CSV to be set correctly?

Comment: For a large dataframe where CSV import or pickle becomes painful, use [pandas HDFStore support](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5). Or the newer `dask` or `ray` backend to Pandas (*"Pandas on Ray: Make Pandas [>=4x] faster by replacing one line of your code"*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `dict` with `zip` , to get the dtype name using `dtype.name`

```
dict(zip(list(df),[df[x].dtype.name for x in df]))

Out[6]: {'A': 'int64', 'B': 'object', 'C': 'float64'}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure consistency between column name and its data-type:

```
dict(([(dataframe[x].name, dataframe[x].dtype.name)  for x in dataframe]))
```